# Application not re-started after phone call

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.1

I am a noob in iPhone app development, I am trying to create an application (with some buttons to call my contacts).

Until yesterday I had OS 3.0 installed on my phone and my application restarted after the call completed. Today I updated my phone to 3.1 OS and I am not able to get the application to restart after the call.

The Call handling application comes up and stays. User has to exit from the call handling application and invoke the application again to proceed further, but this is not solving my application's purpose.

Am I doing something wrong or has the functionality changed in OS 3.1?

I appreciate all the helpful answers.

Thank You,
Ashvin

Answer (score 1):

Apple has indeed changed this in 3.1 and there is no way to go back to the old behavior. If you have access to Apple's iPhone Developer Forums, [see here for the source](https://devforums.apple.com/message/128046#128046).

Another thing that has changed between 3.0 and 3.1 in this area: 3.1 does not ask the user for confirmation anymore before initiating a call that an app invokes with openURL:.